# Can a DDR3 ECC module be used in a slot without ECC?

Tags: ddr, ecc

I have tried for a while to use a DDR3 *SODIMM* module with ECC on the VC709. While I can get the memory that ships with it (Single Rank, 204 PIN, 64 Data Lines) to work easy enough, I cannot get a double rank, ECC, 72 data lines memory to work.

I assumed, that I could just ignore the additional 8 Data lines, however the synchronization fails. **Is there any way in which the memory controller ensures synchronization with all chips of the memory module?**

I have found the [DDR3 specification](https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/docs/jesd-79-3d) to be too cryptic to understand so far.

Comment: Are you sure the ECC memory is otherwise the same? Registered v unregistered, buffered or not, operating voltage?

Comment: @Finbarr: In a moment of extrem frustartion the enlgihtenment came, when I realized that some PCs that are non ECC also do not work with ECC memory, and I dug into the reason: they are pin incompatible for DDR3 :/

Comment: Just to clarify, you are talking about the SO-DIMM form factor. The pinout of "normal" DDR3 and ECC DDR3 is the same.

Comment: @A.K. I am wondering more and more who came up with the pinout specification

Comment: @ted - [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_dynamic_random-access_memory)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I found the answer: For DDR3 the pinout of ECC and non-ECC ram is different as can be seen on page 8 [here](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-ddr2-ecc-so-dimm-paper.pdf).

I spent ages trying to get the timings right, and thought I configured the memory controller incorrectly.